# Example of implementing 'WKNavigationDelegate' method 'didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation' method to follow redirects

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, http-redirect

I need a simple example in Swift to illustrate how I would implement the `WKNavigationDelegate` method `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation` method to follow redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing needs to be done in this method to follow a redirect response. WKWebView will follow a redirect response without any further implementation necessary in the `WKNavigationDelegate` method `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation`.